# Get console.log in HTML

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax

I have written an online editor code which compiles java codes, the problem is that I get the output from the compiler as `console.log()`

**Output** is : `{Warnings: null, Errors: null, Result: "Hello World!↵", Stats: "Compilation time: 0.72 sec, absolute running time:…mory peak: 35 Mb, absolute service time: 1,09 sec", Files: null, …}`

I want the output to be shown in the HTML itself, any solution ??

**So far my code is:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><title> Onile Compile</title
<body>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            var ultimate_test_result = 24;

            var to_compile = {
                "LanguageChoice": "4",
                "Program": $("#code").val(),
                "Input": "",
                "CompilerArgs" : ""
            };

            $.ajax ({
                    url: "https://rextester.com/rundotnet/api",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: to_compile
                }).done(function(data) {
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                    console.log(data); 
                }).fail(function(data, err) {
                    alert("fail " + JSON.stringify(data) + " " + JSON.stringify(err));
                });
        });
        
    });

    </script>
    <textarea id="code" rows="20" cols="100">

  class Rextester {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }
}  
    
    </textarea><br>
    <button id="run">Run</button>
    <br>
    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to print out in html? "Hello world"?

Comment: @Reporter, i want the output `data` to be printed. the data is a JSON which contains all the outputs including "Hello world".

Comment: If so, the way is wrong. You have to execute the java code on server side and send it to client side. Write  a java servlet that takes the request and add the data into response. Then the response contains your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place a div with ID in html and then use `$("#result_id").html(data)' or '$("#result_id").text(data)`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><title> Onile Compile</title
<body>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            var ultimate_test_result = 24;

            var to_compile = {
                "LanguageChoice": "4",
                "Program": $("#code").val(),
                "Input": "",
                "CompilerArgs" : ""
            };

            $.ajax ({
                    url: "https://rextester.com/rundotnet/api",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: to_compile
                }).done(function(data) {
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                    console.log(data); 
                    $("#result").text(data);
                }).fail(function(data, err) {
                    alert("fail " + JSON.stringify(data) + " " + JSON.stringify(err));
                });
        });
        
    });

    </script>
    <textarea id="code" rows="20" cols="100">

  class Rextester {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }
}  
    
    </textarea><br>
    <button id="run">Run</button>
    <br>

    <div id="result"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did not understand what you mean.

Comment: Please look at the answer, I have updated it with code

Comment: I am getting `[object Object]` as the output in HTML.

Comment: My output should be `{Warnings: null, Errors: null, Result: "Hello World!↵", Stats: "Compilation time: 0.72 sec, absolute running time:…mory peak: 35 Mb, absolute service time: 1,09 sec", Files: null, …}`

Comment: If your code is returning a json object, you can use `$("#result").text(JSON.stringify(data));`